# javascript how to refactor this code passing something different inside axios then

Tags: javascript, refactoring

HOw to refractor the code in javascript

```
  const handleClick1 = () => {
    axios.get("someurl.com")
    .then((res) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
          ----- execute something different 
        })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  };

  const handleClick2 = () => {
    axios.get("someurl.com")
    .then((res) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
          ----- execute something different 
        })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  };


  const handleClick3 = () => {
    axios.get("someurl.com")
    .then((res) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
          ----- execute something different 
        })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  };
```

I want to make a function

```
const axios_related = (----- execute something different) => {
    axios.get("someurl.com")
    .then((res) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
          ----- execute something different 
        })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  };
}
```

and replace as

```
const handleClick1 = () => {
    ----- execute something different {
      -- step1
      -- step2
      -- step3
      ---
      -- stepn      
    }

    axios_related(----- execute something different );
  };

  const handleClick2 = () => {
    ----- execute something different {
      -- step1
      -- step2
      -- step3
      ---
      -- stepn      
    }

    axios_related(----- execute something different );
  };


  const handleClick3 = () => {
    ----- execute something different {
      -- step1
      -- step2
      -- step3
      ---
      -- stepn      
    }
    axios_related(----- execute something different );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a higher-order function that takes a callback and calls that inside the `.then`.

```
const makeHandleClick = (callback) => {
  axios.get("someurl.com")
    .then((res) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
          callback(res);
        })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
};
```

```
const handleClick1 = makeHandleClick(callback1);
const handleClick2 = makeHandleClick(callback2);
const handleClick3 = makeHandleClick(callback3);
```

Comment: so its like three layers Eg. 1 - higher order makeHandleClick, 2 - callback1, 3 - handleClick1